# How to erase text from an image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a collection of photos that have text displayed in them.  I'd like to replace that text with a pattern of my choosing.  I'm using OCR to find the text so I know its position already and select it as a region of interest.

For example, given this photo:
[image]

OCR returns the coordinates where the text is:
[image]

I want to replace text to achieve this:
[image]

How do I select, remove, and replace the text using OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is image binaryzation. Since you get the coordinates where the text is, treat the binary image as a mask, the text in the binary image should be 255 in the regions you get, then you can assign other value to the text pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the approximate region of interest, run an OTSU threshold routine on the area and you'll get a binary mask (hopefully, provided the image is not very noisy).

Tinker with that binary mask to your heart's content.